# Windows Workflow Delay problem

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I'm quite new to Workflow and have a question.

I have a While Loop in my designer which checks a conditon.

The while loop works fine and the condtion checking works fine.

What I'm trying to do, is to set a delay so that the while loop only checks the condition every x seconds/minutes. I've tried the delay control inside the while loop, but for some reason, the delay Activity does not pass control back to the while loop to check the condition again. The only property I've set in the Delay activity is : TimeoutDuration = 00:00:10 (10 seconds right?).

Any advice?

Tx

Comment: A little bit more info would help.. how do you host the workflow and what kind of condition are you checking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the VS designer (drag and drop), you will be able to add a Delay Activity into your workflow. The Delay Activity requires a Duration value which is basically a TimeSpan. For example, if you wanted to have a 5-sec delay you would need to assign Duation the following TimeSpan object:

```
               New TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); //0 hours, 0 minutes, 5 seconds
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: am talking about WF4 here, not sure about 3.5 & 3.0 versions!